# Show that the subpartitions $A_{12}$ and $A_{21}$ of a unitary matrix $A$ have identical singular values.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If a unitary matrix $A$ is partitioned as:
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12} \\ 
A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$, where $A_{11} \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times m}$, $A_{22} \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$
Prove that $A_{12}$ and $A_{21}$ have identical singular values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bC}{\mathbb{C}}$Since $A$ is unitary, one the one hand,
$$
 I_{n+m} = A^\ast A = \begin{pmatrix} A_{11}^\ast & A_{21}^\ast \\ A_{12}^\ast & A_{22}^\ast \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} A_{11}^\ast A_{11} + A_{21}^\ast A_{21} & A_{11}^\ast A_{12} + A_{21}^\ast A_{22} \\ A_{12}^\ast A_{11} + A_{22}^\ast A_{21} & A_{12}^\ast A_{12} + A_{22}^\ast A_{22} \end{pmatrix},
$$
and on the other hand,
$$
 I_{n+m} = A A^\ast = \begin{pmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} A_{11}^\ast & A_{21}^\ast \\ A_{12}^\ast & A_{22}^\ast \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} A_{11} A_{11}^\ast + A_{12}A_{12}^\ast & A_{11}A_{21}^\ast + A_{12}A_{22}^\ast \\ A_{21}A_{11}^\ast + A_{22}A_{12}^\ast & A_{21}A_{21}^\ast + A_{22}A_{22}^\ast \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Hence, in particular,
$$
 A_{21}^\ast A_{21} = I_n - A_{11}^\ast A_{11}, \quad A_{12}A_{12}^\ast = I_n - A_{11}A_{11}^\ast.
$$
Now, let $A_{11} = U \Sigma V^\ast$ be an SVD for the $n\times n$ square matrix $A_{11}$. Then
$$
 A_{11}A_{11}^\ast = U \Sigma^2 U^\ast, \quad A_{11}^\ast A_{11} = V \Sigma^2 V^\ast,
$$
so that
$$
 A_{21}^\ast A_{21} = U (I_n-\Sigma^2) U^\ast, \quad A_{12}A_{12}^\ast = V (I_n - \Sigma^2) V^\ast.
$$
In particular, observe that since $A_{21}^\ast A_{21} \geq 0$, $I_n - \Sigma^2 \geq 0$. Since $A_{21}^\ast A_{21}$ and $A_{12}A_{12}^\ast$ are unitarily similar, [it follows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Existence) that the non-zero diagonal entries of $\sqrt{I_n - \Sigma^2}$ are precisely the non-zero singular values of both $A_{21}$ and $A_{12}^\ast$, counted with multiplicity. On the other hand,
$$
 \ker A_{21}^\ast A_{21} = \ker A_{21}, \quad \ker A_{12}A_{12}^\ast = \ker A_{12}^\ast,
$$
so that since $A_{21}^\ast A_{21}$ and $A_{12}A_{12}^\ast$ are unitarily similar,
$$
 \dim\ker A_{21} = \dim\ker A_{21}^\ast A_{21} = \dim\ker A_{12}A_{12}^\ast = \dim\ker A_{12}^\ast
$$
and hence both $A_{21}$ and $A_{12}^\ast$ are either both injective or both have the singular value $0$ with the same multiplicity. Since $A_{12}$ and $A_{12}^\ast$ have the same singular values with the same multiplicities -- an SVD for $A_{12}^\ast$ yields an SVD for $A_{12}$ by taking adjoints -- it therefore follows that $A_{12}$ and $A_{21}$ have the same singular values with the same multiplicities.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how $A_{21}^\ast A_{21} = U (I_n-\Sigma^2) U^\ast$ and $\quad A_{12}A_{12}^\ast = V (I_n - \Sigma^2) V^\ast $ result that $A_{12}$ and $A_{21}$ have the same singular values?

Comment: Since $A_{21}$ and $A_{12}$ are square matrices, the singular values of $A_{21}$ are precisely the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A_{21}^\ast A_{21}$ or, equivalently, $A_{21}A_{21}^\ast$, and the singular values of $A_{12}$ are precisely the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A_{12}^\ast A_{12}$ or, equivalently, $A_{12}A_{12}^\ast$. So, given that $I_n - \Sigma^2$ is a diagonal matrix with non-negative entries...

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that, though everything still carries through identically. For details on how a unitary diagonalisation of $A_{21}^\ast A_{21}$ gives rise to a singular value decomposition of (and, *mutatis mutandis*, how $A_{12}A_{12}^\ast$ gives rise to a singular value decomposition of $A_{12}$), see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Existence, under the subsection "Based on the spectral theorem."

Comment: @Sam Alright, I've fleshed out the last step for you.

Comment: Branimir, thanks a lot for solving this problem.